# Destroy server model does not update id to null

Tags: rest, backbone.js, backbone-relational

after I change to Backbone-Relational my model stopped to work when I call destroy().. I have to ensure that when it removes success on server there will be no more id at client side, so then when I try to save it again my model wont request PUT (update) - throws Record Not Found on server side.

Coffeescript side

```
save: ->        
    if isBlank @model.get("text")
        @model.destroy() # after success it still with same attributes including id!!
    else
        @model.save()
```

Rails side

```
def destroy
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
    @note.destroy        
    respond_with @note # callback is empty
end
```

Bug from Backbone-Relational perhaps? Does Backbone.js update id after destroy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone does not look like it modifies the Model on destruction in any way. Except removing it from its collection if any.

[Check the code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-59)

What it does is triggering the event `destroy` so you easily can listen this event and do whatever you think is the proper behavior in destruction:

```
// code simplified and no tested
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
     this.on( "destroy", this.afterDestroy, this );
  },

  afterDestroy: function(){
    this.set( "id", null );
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks man, I was just curious why backbone.js does not clean your id after success destroy() anyway :/